# 'stopped' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate an image. This animation is playing between two screen transitions. This animation is for showing waiting bar. I am using require-jquery.js and the version is 1.7.1. I am getting an inconsistent error:

> 'stopped' is null or not an object.

Anybody got the same issue? Please share the solution.

Updated Code :

```
    templateFn: Handlebars.compile(
        '<div class="waitingBar"></div>'
    ),

    render: function(parent) {
        this.element = $(this.templateFn());

        this._animate();

        parent.append(this.element);
    },


_animate: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.element.animate({
        "background-position-x": "+=1024px"
    },
    8000,
    "linear",
    function () {
        self.element.css({
            "background-position-x": "-1024"
        });
        self._animate();
    });
}
```

I am getting the error in require-jquery library. Below is the function :
 Library code :

```
      function Animation( elem, properties, options ) {
        var result,
        stopped,
        index = 0,
        length = animationPrefilters.length,
        deferred = jQuery.Deferred().always( function() {
            // don't match elem in the :animated selector
            delete tick.elem;
         }),
         tick = function() {
            if ( stopped ) {
                return false;
            }
            var currentTime = fxNow || createFxNow(),
                remaining = Math.max( 0, animation.startTime + animation.duration - currentTime ),
            // archaic crash bug won't allow us to use 1 - ( 0.5 || 0 ) (#12497)
                temp = remaining / animation.duration || 0,
                percent = 1 - temp,
                index = 0,
                length = animation.tweens.length;

            for ( ; index < length ; index++ ) {
                animation.tweens[ index ].run( percent );
            }

            deferred.notifyWith( elem, [ animation, percent, remaining ]);

            if ( percent < 1 && length ) {
                return remaining;
            } else {
                deferred.resolveWith( elem, [ animation ] );
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"since last one month"* … really..? o.0

Comment: How are you calling this..? what is `this` and `this.element` in this context..? Can you share the minimal code required to reproduce the error, or a demo such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Looks like a method from a jQuery UI widget

Comment: So the error you referenced is one I have seen in IE8. Is this only happening in IE8? Or other browsers as well?

Comment: Can you replicate the error using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I am using Handlebars.js to complie a div which is nothing buit this.element

Comment: The weird thing is I am not even able reproduce in my project. As I said it is inconsitent.

Comment: "I am using only IE8" thats awful. :)

Comment: There is a certain set of conditions that produces this error. It may seem like a "random" error but really, you just haven't discovered what causes it yet.

Comment: The error is in require-jquery.js library line number is 10711

Comment: When it is checking for "if(stopped)" it is throwing the error.

Comment: - @Nick, You told that you have seen this error earlier. Could you tell me what was the root cause in your case?

Comment: I have seen this error come from a previous javascript error causing a variable to be uninitialized, from the scripts being loaded in the wrong order, and from trying to query the DOM before it is ready. Try initializing stopped to false and see if that prevents the error.

Comment: @Nick - But is it appropriate to modify library file?

Comment: Since the error is coming from the library and you must support IE8 you have 2 options: modify the library or don't use it. At the very least you could modify it temporarily and confirm that it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****I solved it myself....here is the solution :**** I have a method called destroy() which is being called when I moved to next page. I am stopping the animation (using .stop()) in destroy() method.  We are calling multiple animations on same element. The later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element. These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately. But since the element reference is there in memory(this.element is not made as null) and the second animation is there in effect queue, it tries to animate again but it will not find data attached to it. So in this case stopped may become null. So when it is trying to check for if(stopped), it might be giving error.

Finally I made .stop() to .stop(true) to clear the queue and I made this.element=null. 
These two changes seem to be working for me..... :)